# Regex match until certain word and clear all leading and trailing whitespaces

Tags: javascript, regex

So I need to trim a certain string in 2 ways (different results)

**myString = '3rd Floor Empire State Building'**, please note that the format of myString could be:

- 13th Floor Burj Khalifa
- 2nd floor Chrysler Building
- 4th flOor Big Ben

Basically what I'm trying to say here is that the word floor is consistent..

So here's what I need to do:

1. Match string until a certain word and remove everything from that word onward.

> so from myString, I just need the word **'3rd'** - what I have so far is: `myString.match(/.+?(?=floor)/ig)` but this code leaves out a space and it becomes '3rd '

2. Match a string until a certain word and remove everything from that word backwards.

> so from myString, I just need the word **'Empire State Building'**.

EDIT: I also need to keep these assumptions in mind, is it possible and how can I make it concise? (one-liner if possible):

- accepts floor or flr
- takes only the first word before the floor/flr (e.g. if output is apartment 2nd flr building OR apartment 2nd floor bldg it should only take 2nd and building/bldg)

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn’t work?

Comment: From my first result, I've tried this: myString.match(/.+?(?=floor)/ig), but it leaves out a space like so: '3rd ' instead of '3rd', for the second result, I haven't seen anything yet.

Comment: Seen anything? What do you mean? You must be able to try something out without seeing it first?

Comment: For the first, you could add matching the space `.+?(?= floor)` https://regex101.com/r/WKKQ8l/1 For the second you can match the first part and replace it with an empty string `.+? floor ` https://regex101.com/r/hmpcxs/1

Comment: `myString.match(/([\s\S]*?)\s*floor\s*([\s\S]*)/i).slice(1)`

Comment: *"Basically what I'm trying to say here is that the word floor is consistent.."* Really? `...Floor,...floor,...flOor...?` Also, when you say *"format"* -- do you mean that the string could be in HTML? ex. `<li>13th FLooR Garbage Dump</li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can use String.[split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
const myString = '3rd Floor Empire State Building';
const certainString = ' Floor ';

let before = myString.split(certainString)[0];
let after = myString.split(certainString)[1];

console.log(before);
console.log(after);
```

---

If case-sensitivity is a concern we can covert them to lower(or upper)-case before comparing. check the snippet below:

```js
const myString = '3rd Floor Empire State Building';
const certainWord = ' Floor ';
//----------------------------------------------
const lowerMyString = myString.toLowerCase();
const lowerCertainWord = certainWord.toLowerCase();
const beforeEndIndex = lowerMyString.indexOf(lowerCertainWord);
const afterStartIndex = beforeEndIndex + lowerCertainWord.length;
const before = myString.slice(0, beforeEndIndex);
const after = myString.slice(afterStartIndex, myString.length);
//----------------------------------------------
console.log(before);
console.log(after);
```

Comment: Floor, floor, fLoor

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, I'd think about that, but he said "certain word". certain word  means certain capital and small letters. we don't want to over-engineer things

Comment: However match /i is case insensitive and so are both my suggestions :)

Comment: @mplungjan consider this; `certain word = 'Floor'` and string is `3rd Floor floortech building`; which is a real bulidng name in austrila;

Comment: My first example handles that

Comment: @mplungjan the `.split()` approach will handle that too, but that concern seems legit, I'd added a case-insensitive `split` too 

Answer (score 0):

With regex:

https://regex101.com/r/a3WlFM/2

```js
const re = /([\s\S]*?)(?:\s+)floor(?:\s+)([\w+ \.\,\?\!]*)/gim

const str = `3rd Floor Empire State Building
13th Floor Burj Khalifa
2nd floor Chrysler Building
4th flOor Big Ben
3rd Floor floortech building` 

match = re.exec(str);
while (match != null) {
  // matched text: match[0]
  // match start: match.index
  // capturing group n: match[n]
  console.log(match[1],"-",match[2])
  match = re.exec(str);
}
```

Or without regex

```js
const myString = '3rd Floor Empire State Building'
const startPos = myString.toLowerCase().indexOf(" floor ")
console.log("Floor:",myString.slice(0,startPos),"Address:",myString.slice(startPos+7))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are not including the space before floor in the lookahead.

Your updated pattern would be `.+?(?= floor)` See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wkJ0BG/1)

---

If you want to match both parts, you could use 2 capturing groups and start with matching a non whitespace char `\S` to prevent an empty string.

Use `/i` for a case insensitive match and if `/g` to get all matches if you want.

```
/(\S.*?) floor (\S.*)/gi
```

The pattern will match

- `(\S.*?)` Capture **group 1**, match a non whitespace char any any char non greedy
- `floor`  Match floor surrounded by spaces
- `(\S.*)` Capture **group 2**, Match a whitespace chars and the rest of the line`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PsuVfR/1)

```js
const regex = /(\S.*?) floor (\S.*)/gi;
const str = `13th Floor Burj Khalifa
2nd floor Chrysler Building
4th flOor Big Ben
3rd Floor Empire State Building
 floor `;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  console.log(m[1]);
  console.log(m[2]);
  console.log("\n");
}
```